# Notify transmission is complete over 20 bytes onCharactersitcChanged BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to fetch data from a Bluetooth LE device that sends data exceeding the 20 bytes which seems to be the limit on how much data can be received at once when `onCharacteristicChanged` is called.

So if the device sends 80 bytes of data upon request then `onCharacteristicChanged` is called `four times`.

**My question is, is there a way to tell when all the bytes have been received so I can request for more data immediately?**

**EDIT**

Here is my code

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback =
            new BluetoothGattCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
                                                    int newState) {
                    String intentAction;
                    Log.d(TAG,"state:"+newState+" status:"+status+" xxx");
                    if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {

                        mBluetoothGatt.requestMtu(517);

                        intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                        initState = INIT_STATE.CONNECTED;
                        //broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server. xxx");
                        Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery xxx:" +
                                mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());
                        Log.d(TAG,"xxx "+mBluetoothGatt.getDevice().getAddress());

                        gattConnected = true;
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                            mBluetoothGatt.requestConnectionPriority(BluetoothGatt.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH);
                        }

                    } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {

                        Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server. xxx "+mBluetoothGatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                        mBluetoothGatt.close();
                        deviceList.remove(0);
                        if (deviceList.size() > 0) {

                            connectToDevice(0);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                // New services discovered
                public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                        //broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
                        boolean foundMatch = false;
                        services = mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
                        for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"Service UUID xxx:"+service.getUuid());
                            if (service.getUuid().equals(SERVICE_UUID)) {
                                foundMatch = true;
                                //*
                                mService = service;
                                mWriteCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(WRITE_UUID);
                                mReadCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(READ_UUID);
                                mCreditCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(WRITE_UUID_2);
                                setCharacteristicNotification(mReadCharacteristic,true);

                                newData = true;
//There is a delay for this write because a mode request is sent first from onDescriptorWrite 
                                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        try {
                                            Thread.sleep(150);
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        byte[] infoRequest = {0x00, 0x02, 0x04, 0x00};
                                        write(infoRequest);
                                    }
                                });
                                t.start();
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: xxx " + status);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
                    //Log.d(TAG,"Charac changed..... xxx");

                    byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
                    int dataSize = data.length;

                    System.arraycopy(data,0,rawBytes,bufferIndex,dataSize);
                    bufferIndex+=dataSize;
// The only way I can tell all the data has been received right now is to check the chunk size.
                    if (dataSize != 20) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"new data xxx");
                        newData = false;
                        bufferIndex = 0;

                        processData();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
                    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                        //if (descriptor.getCharacteristic().getUuid().equals(UUID_TARGET_CHARACTERISTIC)) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Successfully subscribed xxx");
                        //}
                        // first thing I send is mode select request.
                        byte[] infoRequest = {0x06};
                        writeChangeMode(infoRequest);

                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error subscribing");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                        //Write operation successful - process with next chunk!
                        Log.d(TAG,"Write successful xxx");
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status)                   {
                   super.onMtuChanged(gatt, mtu, status);
                   if ( status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS )
                      {
                          Log.d("TAG","call onMtuChanged "+status);
                      }
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#requestMtu(int) to attempt to increase the MTU. The notification maximum size is `MTU - 3`.

There is no procedure defined in the Bluetooth standard to "tell when all bytes have been received" nor "request more data". That is application specific.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately I'm having no luck with setting the MTU size. I can set the MTU and get a "success" response but `onCharacteristcChanged` won't get called anymore. Any other ideas? I'm thinking of using timers but I don't think that's efficient.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can only have one GATT transaction active at a time. You must wait for https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onMtuChanged(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int) before you can, for example, call `writeDescriptor`. And what `mtu` value does `onMtuChanged` give you?

Comment: If I set the MTU to 50 `gatt.requestMtu(50)` I get 50 as mtu value from the callback and 0 as status. If I set it to 3 I don't get a response from the callback `onMtuChanged` and `onCharacteristicChanged` is still called but the limit is still at 20 bytes.

Comment: The value must be at least 23. You should usually try set it to 517 which is the maximum Android supports. Does that work?

Comment: Still no luck. I don't know if this makes any difference but before I can send data request to the device, I have to send a 'change mode' request to a different characteristic which then selects which module I want to request data from, then I can send data request to the main write characteristic that would then return data to `onCharacteristicChanged`. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: What happens then? Do you still get 20 byte chunks or don't you get notifications? Could you edit your question and insert your code, the version you use requestMtu?

Comment: I successfully managed to set the MTU to 256 from a code snippet I found. The trick was to move `discoverServices` from `onConnectionStateChange` to `onMtuChanged` callback. But it looks like min supported SDK is 21.